# How to compile and transplant samba-4.19.0 as small as possible？

Tags: linux, compiling, samba, libraries

I am compiling `samba-4.19.0` on `Debian12` and then porting the compiled content to other systems. At first, I wanted to compile it into a static executable file as much as possible, but I couldn't find a corresponding method, so I had to use a dynamic library to compile. However, there were a lot of compiled `bin` and `lib` files, so porting to other systems was very troublesome. I don't know what method can solve my problem?

```
tar zxvf samba-4.19.0.tar.gz
cd samba-4.19.0/bootstrap/generated-dists/debian12
sudo ./bootstrap.sh
cd ../../../

./configure  --disable-cups  
--sbindir=/home/debian12/x86/samba/smb_install/sbin 
--sysconfdir=/home/debian12/x86/samba/smb_install/etc 
--mandir=/home/debian12/x86/samba/smb_install/man 
--prefix=/home/debian12/x86/samba/smb_install

make -j 4
sudo  make install
```

bin and lib:

```
debian12@gyz:~/x86/samba/smb_install$ ls
bin  bind-dns  etc  include  lib  libexec  private  sbin  share  var
debian12@gyz:~/x86/samba/smb_install$ ls bin
cifsdd       ldbadd     ldbrename  mdsearch  nmblookup      profiles  regtree           samba-tool  smbcontrol  smbspool    smbtree     tdbtool
dbwrap_tool  ldbdel     ldbsearch  mvxattr   ntlm_auth      regdiff   rpcclient         sharesec    smbcquotas  smbstatus   tdbbackup   testparm
dumpmscat    ldbedit    locktest   ndrdump   oLschema2ldif  regpatch  samba-log-parser  smbcacls    smbget      smbtar      tdbdump     wbinfo
gentest      ldbmodify  masktest   net       pdbedit        regshell  samba-regedit     smbclient   smbpasswd   smbtorture  tdbrestore  winexe
debian12@gyz:~/x86/samba/smb_install$ ls lib
bind9                           libndr-krb5pac.so.0            libsamba-errors.so.1.0.0                               libsmbconf.so.0.0.1
gensec                          libndr-krb5pac.so.0.0.1        libsamba-hostconfig.so                                 libsmbldap.so
idmap                           libndr-nbt.so                  libsamba-hostconfig.so.0                               libsmbldap.so.2
krb5                            libndr-nbt.so.0                libsamba-hostconfig.so.0.0.1                           libsmbldap.so.2.1.0
ldb                             libndr-nbt.so.0.0.1            libsamba-passdb.so                                     libtevent-util.so
libdcerpc-binding.so            libndr.so                      libsamba-passdb.so.0                                   libtevent-util.so.0
libdcerpc-binding.so.0          libndr.so.3                    libsamba-passdb.so.0.28.0                              libtevent-util.so.0.0.1
libdcerpc-binding.so.0.0.1      libndr.so.3.0.1                libsamba-policy.cpython-311-x86-64-linux-gnu.so        libwbclient.so
libdcerpc-samr.so               libndr-standard.so             libsamba-policy.cpython-311-x86-64-linux-gnu.so.0      libwbclient.so.0
libdcerpc-samr.so.0             libndr-standard.so.0           libsamba-policy.cpython-311-x86-64-linux-gnu.so.0.0.1  libwbclient.so.0.16
libdcerpc-samr.so.0.0.1         libndr-standard.so.0.0.1       libsamba-util.so                                       nss_info
libdcerpc-server-core.so        libnetapi.so                   libsamba-util.so.0                                     pkgconfig
libdcerpc-server-core.so.0      libnetapi.so.1                 libsamba-util.so.0.0.1                                 private
libdcerpc-server-core.so.0.0.1  libnetapi.so.1.0.0             libsamdb.so                                            process_model
libdcerpc-server.so             libnss_winbind.so.2            libsamdb.so.0                                          python3.11
libdcerpc-server.so.0           libnss_wins.so.2               libsamdb.so.0.0.1                                      security
libdcerpc-server.so.0.0.1       libsamba-credentials.so        libsmbclient.so                                        service
libdcerpc.so                    libsamba-credentials.so.1      libsmbclient.so.0                                      vfs
libdcerpc.so.0                  libsamba-credentials.so.1.0.0  libsmbclient.so.0.7.0
libdcerpc.so.0.0.1              libsamba-errors.so             libsmbconf.so
libndr-krb5pac.so               libsamba-errors.so.1           libsmbconf.so.0
```